# Creating custom helper available in views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view-helpers

I have too much text utility methods, like `MakeShortText(string text, int length)`, `RemoveTags(string text)`, `TimeAgo(DateTime date)` and other.
I want to access them from separate helper like in next example:

```
@Text().MakeShortText(Model.Text, 10)
```

Is it possible to create such extension? Or I have to make extension for HtmlHelper like this:

```
@Html.Text().MaksShortText(Model.Text, 10)
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could start by defining a custom `TextHelper`:

```
public class TextHelper
{
    public TextHelper(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        ViewContext = viewContext;
    }

    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; private set; }
}
```

and then have all your methods be extension methods of this `TextHelper`:

```
public static class TextHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MakeShortText(
        this TextHelper textHelper, 
        string text,
        int value
    )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could define a custom web page:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        Text = new TextHelper(ViewContext);
    }

    public TextHelper Text { get; private set; }
}
```

then in your `~/Views/web.config` (**not** in `~/web.config`) configure this custom web page as base page for your Razor views using the `pageBaseType` attribute:

```
<pages pageBaseType="AppName.Web.Mvc.MyWebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and then in your views you will be able to use:

```
@Text.MakeShortText(Model.Text, 10)
```

And if you wanted to use the following syntax as shown in your question:

```
@Text().MakeShortText(Model.Text, 10)
```

simply modify the custom view engine so that `Text` is not a property but a method that will return an instance of the `TextHelper`. Or even return the `HtmlHelper` instance so that you don't need to move your existing extension methods to `TextHelper`:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public HtmlHelper Text()
    {
        return Html;
    }
}
```

---

The second syntax is also possible:

```
@Html.Text().MaksShortText(Model.Text, 10)
```

Simply define a custom `Text()` extension for the `HtmlHelper` class:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static TextHelper Text(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return new TextHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

and then the same way as in the first case you would have your custom methods be extension methods of this `TextHelper` class.

Comment: Thank you for so accurate and detailed answer. It was very helpful. But i don't understand why I need ViewContext parameter in TextHelper's ctor?

Comment: @EvgenyLevin, so that you have access to the `HttpContext` in your custom extension methods. Things like the Request, Response, Session, RouteData, ... are normally useful in a helper. You also could call other extension methods on say for example the HtmlHelper class like TextBoxFor, ... You could of course remove it if you don't need it.